# convert freestyle job to pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the below graph job definition (via downstream) and I want to migrate it to pipeline with parallel options.

```
          A
        /   \
       B    C
      / \  /
     E   D

 A -> B, C 
 B -> E, D 
 C -> D
```

B and C can run in parallel, D need to wait till B and C finished and E can run after B finished.

How I can do the same in pipeline ?

I tried the below, but

```
stage 'Stage 1'
build 'A'

parallel one: {
    build 'B'
}, second: {
    build 'C'
}

build 'D'
build 'E'
```

in this configuration E will wait till C job finished.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you just put build E inside the parallel block with B it will happen when build B is done. I think you can also add wait: false to have the parallel step not wait for the build. This might be a problem if you need to build something else after build E, though.

```
stage 'Stage 1'
build 'A'

parallel one: {
    build 'B'
    build 'E', wait: false
}, second: {
    build 'C'
}

build 'D'
```

Answer (score -1):

You should set node where build should be ececuted: e.g.

```
node {
   stage 'Build A'
   build 'A'
}
```

I think this resolve your problems.

Comment: my problem is not in the node. I don't know how to set the same flow dependency in the pipeline.